# Implementation of line of credit

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence

> [A series of agreements are expected during the visits, including the implementation of an $800 million Line of Credit to the Maldives.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/itinerary-symbolism/article27690240.ece)

I don't understand the meaning of the term **implementation of line of credit**. Line of credit is an amount of money how can this be implemented. I think the sentence is semantically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

***[Implement;](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/it/amp/inglese/implement)***

> to start using a plan or system:
>
> - The changes to the national health system will be implemented next year.

So the idea is that if a line of credit that has been set up and is  available for use.

Answer (score 0):

With this example:

> A series of agreements are expected during the visits, including the implementation of an $800 million Line of Credit to the Maldives.

There are two key ideas:

- **the implementation**
- **a line of credit**

### A line of credit

A line of credit,  or a "credit line", simply means "**a loan**".    (See [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/line-of-credit), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line%20of%20credit))

You simplified the sentence to "**implementation of line of credit**", but you're missing the word "a" or "an", because it's hidden in front of "$800 million."   When you restore the word "an" ("a"), you have:

> the implementation of a Line of Credit

Implementation means (as @user070221 stated) **the beginning**, or to **start using a system**, so you have:

> **The start of a loan.**

In the full sentence,

> A series of agreements are expected during the visits,  including **the start of a Loan to the Maldives**.